# Blazor/.Net6.0 Error RZ2005 and RZ1011 why is it occurring?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I am getting the following errors when I try build my code that I cannot see any issues with.

- Error    RZ2005  The 'section` directive must appear at the start of the line.
- Error    RZ1011  The 'section' directives value(s) must be separated by whitespace.

Here are the related snippets of code that the issue has originated from

Employee.razor

```
<div>
    <h4>Sections:</h4>
    @foreach(var section in Sections)
    {
        <p>@section.SectionName</p>
    }
</div>
```

Employee.razor.cs

```
[Inject]
public IUserRatingDataService UserRatingDataService { get; set; }
public List<UserRating> Sections { get; set; }
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {

     UserRating = await UserRatingDataService.GetSections();

 }
```

IUserRatingDataService.cs

```
 public interface IUserRatingDataService
 {
     Task<List<UserRating>> GetSections();
 }
```

UserRatingDataService.cs

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public UserRatingDataService(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

public async Task<List<UserRating>> GetSections()
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/userrating/sections");

  
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var sections = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<UserRating>>(json);

    return sections;
}
```

API BACKEND CODE
UserRatingController.cs

```
 public class UserRatingController : Controller
 {
     private readonly IUserRatingRepository _userRepository;

     public UserRatingController(IUserRatingRepository userRepository)
     {
         _userRepository = userRepository;
     }

 [HttpGet("sections")]
 public IActionResult GetSections()
 {
     var sections = _userRepository.GetSections();

     // Project sections to anonymous type
     var sectionList = sections.Select(x => new
     {
         x.SectionId,
         x.SectionName
     });

     return Ok(sectionList);

 }
```

UserRatingRepository.cs

```
 public class UserRatingRepository : IUserRatingRepository
 {
     private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

     public UserRatingRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext)
     {
         _appDbContext = appDbContext;
     }

     public IEnumerable<UserRating> GetSections()
     {
         return _appDbContext.UserRating
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => x)
            .DistinctBy(x => x.SectionId);
     }
```

IUserRating.cs

```
    public interface IUserRatingRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<UserRating> GetSections();
```

With the error being highlighted as from this block specifically:

```
  @foreach(var section in Sections)
  {
      <p>@section.SectionName</p>
  }
```

Im new to blazor so this has my completely stuck any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

`section` is a [reserved word in Razor code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sections), change your code to something like this instead:

```
@foreach(var sect in Sections)
{
    <p>@sect.SectionName</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks that resolved that issue. Now my new issue is the userRating on initialized is a null object instead of being a service class type

Comment: That's a different issue, if you can't fix it, then ask another question.